# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'EveAI.Live.Character.CharacterSheet'

Tags: c#

First off I am just learning C# so I am a little out of my depth here

```
using EveAI.Live;
using EveAI.Live.Character;

public CharacterSheet CharSheet(string API, int KEY, int USER)
    {
        string Charsname = null;
        CharacterSheet CharSheet = new CharacterSheet();
        EveApi api = new EveApi(KEY, API, USER);
        CharacterSheet csname = api.GetCharacterSheet();
        Charsname = csname.Name;
        return Charsname;
    }
```

VS is throwing the error for the line "return Charsname;"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is expecting `CharacterSheet` while you're returning the `csname.Name` which is a string.

I suspect you either want to change your method to return a `string` instead of `CharacterSheet`. Or return `csname` instead of `csname.Name`.

```
public string CharSheet(string API, int KEY, int USER)
{
    string Charsname = null;
    CharacterSheet CharSheet = new CharacterSheet();
    EveApi api = new EveApi(KEY, API, USER);
    CharacterSheet csname = api.GetCharacterSheet();
    Charsname = csname.Name;
    return Charsname;
}
```

or

```
public CharacterSheet CharSheet(string API, int KEY, int USER)
{
    CharacterSheet CharSheet = new CharacterSheet();
    EveApi api = new EveApi(KEY, API, USER);
    CharacterSheet csname = api.GetCharacterSheet();
    return csname;
}
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is to pull the name from the api listed.  When I put in csname.Name it should return just the name field.  There are 30+ fields that are returned by that api.

This is a small example of what can be gotten from it:

      public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirthLocalTime { get; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Race { get; set; }
        public int SkillpointTotal { get; }
        public List<CharacterSheet.LearnedSkill> Skills { get; }

Comment: I am trying to put the name from csname.Name into Charsname so I can grab it from this class on another form.

Comment: Like @Phill said you should return `csname` instead of `Charsname` as the return type for your function is `CharacterSheet` and not `string`. Then whenever you want to use the Name you can use use the `.Name` method of created object. Or better you can make a getter+setter method inside your class.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance.  It took me a few tries to get what you were saying.  Thanks!